# Copy top level group rows only

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large range that is aggregate into several levels of groups. I want to copy only the rows visible at the current outline level. For example, if I collapse all rows to the first outline level I want to then be able to copy just the rows at the 1st outline level and paste into a different sheet/range.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using vba...

Comment: Are the levels by row or by column?

Comment: Can you submit a screenshot?

Answer (score 6):

There is an option in Microsoft Excel which allows you to select only visible cells, rows or columns. This command can be added to the toolbar.  To add the "Select Visible Cells" command:

In MS Excel 2007:
Right click on the toolbar on top and click Customize Quick Access toolbar.
Under Choose Command From drop down menu, select Commands Not in the Ribbon.
Scroll down and click on Select Visible Cells.
Click on Add and OK.

In MS Excel 2003:
Right click on the toolbar on top and click Customize.
Go to Commands tab and select Edit under Categories.
Scroll down the list under Commands and click on Select Visible Cells.
Now drag and drop the command to the toolbar.

Comment: This command, also accessible by the (Alt)+; keyboard shortcut, is very versatile; it also applies when rows and/or columns have been hidden manually or by a filter.  Thanks for telling us about the toolbar option.